# How can I save any sentence using short-cut key for future use?

Tags: editors

Using the tool 'macro'  in MS-word we can save any text 'word' or 'sentences'through a short cut key and use them using that key. As for example, I want to create 
a short cut key of the sentence `This is a macro tool.`to  use later.  In MS word we can save this sentence using 'Ctrl+K'(say).If I want to get the sentence
``This is a macro tool'' I have to press 'Ctrl+K'. Is there any such way in Latex ?

Comment: The key bindings are a function of the editor, but you have not said which editor you use. In latex of course you can define a macro as `\newcommand\myword{This is a macro tool}` and use it as `\myword`, But I think you are asking about an unspecified editor.

Comment: I am using 'kile' on the system ubuntu.

Comment: Have a look at `autokey` then... There are nice tutorials available, I wrote a German article on the installation once. http://uweziegenhagen.de/?p=1535, http://uweziegenhagen.de/?p=1590

Comment: I know nothing of Kile (but some people here use it I think, so you will probably get an answer) but generally since TeX is a macro processor, people use (La)TeX macros for such abbreviations rather than editor shortcuts.

Answer (score 3):

I use several tools for this purpose, depending on the operating system:

- Windows: Autohotkey
- Mac OS X: Textexpander
- Linux: Autokey

As I do most of my work under Windows I know `Autohotkey` best. Here are a few of my shortcuts:

```
:*:desc#::\begin{{}description{}}`r\item[]`r\item[]`r\item[]`r\end{{}description{}}{UP 3}{LEFT}
:*:enum#::\begin{{}enumerate{}}`r\item `r\item `r\item `r\end{{}enumerate{}}{UP 3}
:*:f#::\frac{{}{}}{{}{}}{LEFT 3}
:*:g#::
   Gestern = %A_Now%
   EnvAdd, Gestern, -1, Days
   FormatTime, Gestern, %Gestern%, dd.MM.yyyy
   Send, %Gestern%
   Return
:*:h#::
   Heute = %A_Now%
   FormatTime, Heute, %Heute%, yyyyMMdd
   Send, %Heute%
   Return
:*:item#::\begin{{}itemize{}}`r\item `r\item `r\item `r\end{{}itemize{}}{UP 3}
:*:s#::\section{{}{}}{LEFT}
:*:ss#::\subsection{{}{}}{LEFT}
:*:sss#::\subsubsection{{}{}}{LEFT}
```

`Autohotkey` can calculate dates, a feature I really like. So by typing `h#` I get today's date in YYYYMMDD. I wished I had learnt about this tool when I started TeXing...

Autokey has similar features plus it can run `Python`-scripts.